# Множественное число слова "знание"

Tags: множественное-число

Можно ли сказать "знания иностранных языков" (знания - им. падеж, мн. ч.)? Или "знание иностранных языков" (им. падеж, ед. ч.) - единственно верный вариант? И оговорено ли это в каких-нибудь правилах?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В правилах - нет, в словарных статьях - да, оговорено.

> ЗНАНИЕ, -я; ср. 1. Обобщённые представления о свойствах объективного
> мира, связях и отношениях между объектами, хранящиеся и
> воспроизводимые в сознании; осведомлённость в чём-л. З. людей, жизни.
> З. законов развития. З. духовной жизни народа. // Владение навыками
> практических действий в каких-л. обстоятельствах, умение пользоваться
> чем-л. З. столярного ремесла. З. грамоты, языка. Практическое з.
> компьютера. Со знанием дела говорить, отвечать и т. п. (будучи хорошо
> осведомлённым, опытным в чём-л.). **2. только мн.: знания.**
> Совокупность сведений, познаний в какой-л. области человеческой
> деятельности; обладание сведениями о чём-л. Знания инженера. Получить
> в школе прочные знания. Знания по архитектуре. Истинные знания
> существуют в виде законов науки. Знания в области математики.
> Совокупность знаний в области животноводства. Специалист с хорошими
> знаниями. 3. Система сведений о закономерностях развития природы,
> общества и т. п.; наука. Всякое новое з. - подведение итогов какого-л.
> исследования. Функцией знания является обобщение разрозненных
> представлений о закономерностях природы, общества и мышления.

[**Большой толковый словарь**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x)

Обратите внимание на пункт 2, где подчеркивается: только множественное число. Все приведённые в качестве примеров "знания" абстрактны, оторваны от конкретики ("Специалист с хорошими знаниями").

В Вашем случае указано на конкретное знание - знание языков.

Единственно верный вариант - "знание иностранных языков".

Answer (score 2):

> Можно ли сказать "знания иностранных языков" (знания - им. падеж, мн.
>   ч.)? Или "знание иностранных языков" (им. падеж, ед. ч.) - единственно
>   верный вариант? И оговорено ли это в каких-нибудь правилах? Спасибо.

В вашем случае множественное число противоречит стилистике, если не грамматике.

Слово *знание* имеет множественное число, но употребление его ограничено обычно собирательным контекстом ("всяческие знания") и отдельными случаями противопоставления ("оба знания нужны").

Кузнецов (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x) выделяет три значения слово "знание".

ЗНАНИЕ; ЗНАНЬЕ, -я; ср.

1. Обобщённые представления о свойствах объективного мира, связях и отношениях между объектами, хранящиеся и воспроизводимые в сознании; осведомлённость в чём-л. З. людей, жизни. З. законов развития. З. духовной жизни народа. // Владение навыками практических действий в каких-л. обстоятельствах, умение пользоваться чем-л. З. столярного ремесла. З. грамоты, языка. Практическое з. компьютера. Со знанием дела говорить, отвечать и т. п. (будучи хорошо осведомлённым, опытным в чём-л.).
2. только мн.: знания. Совокупность сведений, познаний в какой-л. области человеческой деятельности; обладание сведениями о чём-л. Знания инженера. Получить в школе прочные знания. Знания по архитектуре. Истинные знания существуют в виде законов науки. Знания в области математики. Совокупность знаний в области животноводства. Специалист с хорошими знаниями.
3. Система сведений о закономерностях развития природы, общества и т. п.; наука. Всякое новое з. - подведение итогов какого-л. исследования. Функцией знания является обобщение разрозненных представлений о закономерностях природы, общества и мышления.

Так вот, если 2-е значение имеет только множественное число, то 1-е (обычно) и 3-е (почти абсолютно) значение множественного числа не имеют. Ваш пример - из первого значения, хотя и третье недалеко. Так что лучше без особой нужды множественное тут не употреблять.

Answer (score 1):

Практика употребления слова такова, что в данном выражении (знание **чего**) обязательно единственное число. С множественным числом возможно выражение "*знания в области* иностранных языков". Почему так сложилось? Видимо, потому, что в единственном числе слово "знани**е**" сохраняет связь с **переходным глаголом** "*знать (что)*" и в силу этого - акцент на факте "знания (незнания) кем-то *чего-то*", в то время как множественное число (знани**я**) образовано не напрямую от глагола, а через отглагольное существительное единственного числа, и потому не сохраняет подразумеваемого вопроса "чего", который связан с вопросом "*(знать) что*?" при исходном переходном глаголе. По значению слово "знани**я**" акцентируется не на *факте знания* (кем-то чего-то), а на *предмете знания*.

Comment: *Видимо, потому, что в единственном числе слово "знание" сохраняет связь с переходным глаголом* - Вот уж переходность тут никаким боком. Это просто отвлеченное понятие, которые нормативно не поддаются счету ни в каком смысле. Как, скажем, любовь или благосостояние. Причем "знание" в отдельных значения не только имеет множественное, но и вообще pluralia tantum, Примеры- см. мой ответ